# Get additional security user fields without calling findByUsername

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm calling the `findUserByUsername()` method to get the `name` field in the `User` entity and I'm wondering if there's any better to do it without having to execute an addional query

AuthenticationController.java

```
@PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> login (@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest userLogin) {
        try {
            Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userLogin.username(), userLogin.password()));
            String token = tokenService.generateToken(authentication);

            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsername(authentication.getName());

            AuthenticationResponse response = new AuthenticationResponse(user.get().getName(), token);

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(response);

        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }
```

SecurityUser.java

```
public class SecurityUser implements UserDetails {

    private final User user;

    public SecurityUser (User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return user
                .getRoles()
                .stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SecurityUser{" +
                "user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your security configuration is set up, you can use `authentication.getName()`, as it usually maps to the username field. This would be the case with `formLogin()` for example, which uses the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` under the covers.